# How can I decompile an exe protected by a PE packer?

Tags: exe, portable-executable

I wanted to get the source code from an exe. I have been investigating and It can be done by reverse engineering. I found a repo called ILSpy that allows me to decompile an exe to get the source code but when using it only outputs an error saying that the exe is protected by a PE packer.

Again I have been looking for information and I saw a tool called CFF Explorer which can be used to know the PE packer used to protect the exe. It works properly but I don't know how to interpret the information. Also tried using PEiD but it just outputs "Not a valid PE file". I tried it with other exe and worked correctly so it is not PEiD's failure. Maybe there is no PE packer and ILSpy was wrong?

So how do I know the PE packer used and how can I get rid of it if possible?

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: You might get better answers here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/